# Angular6 FormControl checkbox don't update FormGroup value

Tags: angular, angular-forms, form-control, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working with Angular ( v 6.1.3 ) and I'm using a FormControl with a checkbox input, but, when I click on the checkbox, the value of the complete form it doesn't change.
The structure of the form is a bit complex, because I'm using a FormGroup with FormArray.

Here the code :
Component.ts

```
  export class BusinessFilterComponent implements OnInit {
  businessFilterForm: FormGroup;
  ......... some other code 

  ngOnInit() {
    ......... some other code

    this.businessFilterForm = new FormGroup({
        "branchesTypes": new FormArray([]),
        "corporatesForms": new FormArray([]),
        "employeesRange": new FormArray([]),
        "revenuesRange": new FormArray([])
    });

    for(let k in branchesTypes){
      let control = new FormGroup({
        id : new FormControl(branchesTypes[k].id),
        description : new FormControl(branchesTypes[k].description),
        selected : new FormControl(true)
      });
      (<FormArray>this.businessFilterForm.get('branchesTypes')).controls.push(control);
    }

    for(let k in corporatesForms){
      let control = new FormGroup({
        id : new FormControl(corporatesForms[k].id),
        description : new FormControl(corporatesForms[k].description),
        selected : new FormControl(true)
      });
      (<FormArray>this.businessFilterForm.get('corporatesForms')).controls.push(control);
    }

    for(let k in employeesRange){
      let control = new FormGroup({
        id : new FormControl(employeesRange[k].id),
        description : new FormControl(employeesRange[k].description),
        selected : new FormControl(true)
      });
      (<FormArray>form.get('employeesRange')).controls.push(control);
    }

    for(let k in revenuesRange){
      let control = new FormGroup({
        id : new FormControl(revenuesRange[k].id),
        description : new FormControl(revenuesRange[k].description),
        selected : new FormControl(true)
      });
      (<FormArray>this.businessFilterForm.get('revenuesRange')).controls.push(control);
    }
    ....... some other code

  }

  getBranchesTypes() {
    return (<FormArray>this.businessFilterForm.get('branchesTypes')).controls;
  }

  getCorporatesForms() {
    return (<FormArray>this.businessFilterForm.get('corporatesForms')).controls;
  }

  getEmployeesRange() {
    return (<FormArray>this.businessFilterForm.get('employeesRange')).controls;
  }

  getRevenuesRange() {
    return (<FormArray>this.businessFilterForm.get('revenuesRange')).controls;
  }

}
```

Component.html

```
    <form class="form-filtri" [formGroup]="businessFilterForm" *ngIf="businessFilterForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Tipo di azienda</label>
    <ul class="categorie-selezione" formArrayName="branchesTypes">
                <li *ngFor="let branchType of getBranchesTypes(); let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
          <input type="checkbox" formControlName="selected" id="branchType{{ branchType.get('id').value }}" class="cursor-pointer">
          <label for="branchType{{ branchType.get('id').value }}" class="cursor-pointer">&nbsp;{{ branchType.get('description').value }} </label>
                </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Forma di azienda</label>
    <ul class="categorie-selezione" formArrayName="corporatesForms">
                <li *ngFor="let corporateForm of getCorporatesForms(); let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
          <input type="checkbox" formControlName="selected" id="corporateForm{{ corporateForm.get('id').value }}" class="cursor-pointer">
          <label for="corporateForm{{ corporateForm.get('id').value }}" class="cursor-pointer">&nbsp;{{ corporateForm.get('description').value }} </label>
                </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Numero di dipendenti</label>
    <ul class="categorie-selezione" formArrayName="employeesRange">
                <li *ngFor="let employeeRange of getEmployeesRange(); let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
          <input type="checkbox" formControlName="selected" id="employeeRange{{ employeeRange.get('id').value }}" class="cursor-pointer">
          <label for="employeeRange{{ employeeRange.get('id').value }}" class="cursor-pointer">&nbsp;{{ employeeRange.get('description').value }} </label>
                </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Fatturato</label>
    <ul class="categorie-selezione" formArrayName="revenuesRange">
                <li *ngFor="let revenueRange of getRevenuesRange(); let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
          <input type="checkbox" formControlName="selected" id="revenueRange{{ revenueRange.get('id').value }}" class="cursor-pointer">
          <label for="revenueRange{{ revenueRange.get('id').value }}" class="cursor-pointer">&nbsp;{{ revenueRange.get('description').value }} </label>
                </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I do some stuff with the checkbox and at the end I'm doing this.businessFilterForm.value, the values of all the checkbox are the same as at initial time ( when I set true as FormControl(true) value )

I'm losing my mind searching what's the problem and what could be the solution, but I got stuck.
Could someone help me ?

Thank you so much

Comment: Do you need ids on your controlls? Consider creating stackblitz for that

Comment: No need to call get functions from the template. You can directly iterate form array. Can you create a stackblitz demo ?